# Find the area of triangle formed by the tangents of parabola and chord of contacts

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

> Find the area of the triangle formed by the tangents from the point $(h, k)$ to the parabola $y^2=4ax$ and the chord of contact.

I find the the tangents from external points $(h,k)$, i.e.
$$(y^2-4ax)(k^2-4ah)=(ky-2a(x+h))^2$$
Again the chord of contact of the given parabola is $ky=2a(x+h)$. Then we try to find out three extremities.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Please show your work first.

Comment: I find the the tangents from external points $(h,K)$, i.e. $(y^2-4ax)(k^2-4ah)=(ky-2a(x+h))$. again the chord of contact of the given parabola is $ky=2a(x+h)$. Then we try to find out three extremites

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be the points of contact.

Substitute the chord $ky=2a(x+h)$ into the parabola $y^2=4ax$ to obtain a quadratic equation in $y$. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the roots. So we have $y_1+y_2$ and $y_1y_2$. $(y_1-y_2)^2=(y_1+y_2)^2-4y_1y_2$.

$k(y_1-y_2)=2a(x_1-x_2)$ and so we can find the distance between the two points of contact.

The distance between the point $(h,k)$ and the chord of contact is $\displaystyle \left|\frac{2a(h)-k(k)+2ah}{\sqrt{4a^2+k^2}}\right|$.

Multiply the two distances and divide it by $2$, we have the area.